# Push notification for apps that are not running?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm studying GCM now and as far as I see it works for running apps, passing a payload to them and letting the app to deal with it by itself.

However, I've seen apps that are received notifications (or maybe it was Android receiving and showing notification related to the app) when not running. For example, device was turned off. I'm just turning the device on, then turning on Wi-Fi and after a second I see new notifications with the app's icon on it and some text related to in-app events.

How could I implement that kind of notifications?

Comment: iam not familiar with gcm .. but a way is to declare a broadcast (Onbootcomplete) that starts a (remote)service.. the app isnt runnig but your (remote) service can communicate with your server .. and show up a notification

Comment: "I see it works for running apps" -- no, it works for any installed app that has set up GCM support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare the Broadcast Receiver and the GCMIntentService in the mainfest will allow the Application to get any Message (GCM Included of crouse) if the application not running

[BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
[Example and Documantion](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

For being able to receive GCM's push notifications while the app isn't running you should set up an android IntentService, make it run in the background and set the BroadcastReceiver to listen for GCM notifications.

For more information refer to Google's documentation: [GCM information](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com/products/mobile-app-engagement). I'm using it no my android app.